# Configuring sendmail to redirect all e-mail to a single user

Tags: email, sendmail

I am installing Bugzilla and I want to prevent it from sending out e-mails, which instead should be sent to a user on the local machine.

I have this line in my /etc/mail/sendmail.mc:

```
FEATURE(`virtusertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')
```

I added the following line to the top of /etc/mail/virtusertable (the rest is comments):

```
@mydomain.com     myusername
```

I then ran the following comands:

```
$ makemap hash /etc/mail/virtusertable < /etc/mail/virtusertable
$ m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
```

I then restarted the sendmail server.  However, when I send an e-mail to myusername@mydomain.com via the mail command, I still receive it in my web-based inbox, which is not what I want.  I want it to be delievered only to myusername on the local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took David's advice and installed Postfix.  It was amazingly easy to set up.  I followed [these instructions](http://fedorasolved.org/server-solutions/postfix-mail-server) to configure main.cf, then all I had to do was add the following line to /etc/postfix/virtual:

```
@mydomain.com     myusername
```

Then execute the following commands:

```
$ postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
$ postfix reload
```

And voilà!  All mail sent from the local machine to any address @mydomain.com is instead sent to the local user myusername.

Comment: Yeah, Postfix or exim are so much easier to set up than Sendmail. Even people who've used Sendmail for 20 years complain about its config files.

Comment: I had a similar requirement and also went down this route. The linked instructions are unfortunately no longer there, one step I missed initially is to add the line `virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual` to main.cf

Answer (score 3):

Please do yourself, and the world, a favour and replace Sendmail with something easier to configure and maintain, like Exim or Postfix. I would normally vote down answers that said "use a different product", but in the case of Sendmail, I think it's worth the risk. Sendmail is very complex to configure compared to modern MTAs and should only be used if you have an existing complex Sendmail infrastructure and you have considerable Sendmail experience.

Also, I don't know if it's a typo or not, but you have

```
m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/endmail.cf
```

Notice the endmail.cf, rather than sendmail.cf.